# Backbone rendering view by query string value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have dynamic links and want to render views by those query string of the links.

The link format be like :

```
mysite.com/#content/id/subid/queryString=test1 //test1 is dynamic, it can be test1,test2 or the other value
```

I can get the query string by `this.options.queryString` in the main view.

**Main View** :

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/Content/mainTemplate.html",
    "views/test1",
    "views/test2"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, MainTemplate, test1, test2){

    var mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize : function(option){
      },
      event : {

      },
      render : function(){
        var _content= _.template(MainTemplate);
        this.$el.append(_content);

        var view = this.option.queryString;
        var renderView = new view();
        $("#subDiv").html(renderView.render().$el);
     }
  });
  return mainView;
});
```

What I am trying to do is : when the queryString = test1, I will render a view name `test1`.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: This is not a querystring, a querystring is supposed to be prepended with `?` e.g. `mysite.com/#content/id/subid/?queryString=test1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines (providing you have a real query string preprended with `?` like I commented). Note this is just pseudo-code.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/Content/mainTemplate.html',
    'views/test1',
    'views/test2'
], function($, _, Backbone, MainTemplate, test1, test2) {
    'use strict';

    var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
        getParameterByName: function(name) {
            var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
            return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        },

        render: function(){
            var _content= _.template(MainTemplate);
            this.$el.append(_content);

            var SubView = require('views/' + this.getParameterByName('queryString'));
            var subView = new SubView();

            this.$el('.sub-div').html(subView.render().$el);
        }
    });

    return MainView;
});
```

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught Error: Module name "" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Check my updated answer (`require('views/' + ...`). Also the result of  `this.getParameterByName('queryString')` should be "test1" or "test2" otherwise it won't work - to include views which you didn't add to the top in `define` the code would be slightly different